# Make an AngularJS service and working with promise

Tags: angularjs, promise

I would like to make a service which loads a JSON file and the provide some methods to work with the result.

```
Blog.service('ArticleService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.loadArticles = function() {
        return $http.get('data/articles.json');
    };

    this.getArticles = function () {
        // return the json
    };

    this.getArticle = function (id) {
        // work with the json
    };
}]);
```

And the controller:

```
Blog.controller('BlogController', function ($scope, ArticleService) {
    console.log(ArticleService.getArticles());

    console.log(ArticleService.getArticle(1));
});
```

I'd like to cache the result of my request and then work with this result in my methods, `getArticles` and `getArticle`.

Comment: I'm afraid what you want isn't possible without creating a promise in your service and passing that promise to the controller, as @sylwester wrote in his answer.
Why do you want to cache the result? The HTTP server should tell you if the resource is cachable or not, not the client.

Comment: I just don't want to make 3 HTTP requests if I have 3 methods which works with the JSON data. What is the best way to achieve this? Imagine that I have to use `getArticle(id)` multiple times, I won't repeat the way I get one article in multiple controllers.

Comment: Simply cache the returned promise in your service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your comment, if you want to do only 1 request, then I'll suggest saving the $http promise in a variable in your service and returning that variable in getArticles.

```
Blog.service('ArticleService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.loadArticles = function() {
        return $http.get('data/articles.json');
    };

    var articles;
    this.getArticles = function () {
        if (!articles) {
            articles = this.loadArticles();
        }
        return articles;
    };

    this.getArticle = function (id) {
        // work with the json
    };

}]);
```

Or better yet, load the `articles` variable on init:

```
Blog.service('ArticleService', ['$http' '$q', function ($http, $q) {

    var articles = (function() {
        return $http.get('data/articles.json');
    })();

    this.getArticles = function () {
        return articles;
    };

    this.getArticle = function (id) {
        // Return a promise that will be resolved with the correct article.
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        articles.then(function (arts) {
            arts.forEach(function (art) {
                if (art.id === id) {
                    deferred.resolve(art);
                }
            });
        });
        return deferred.promise;  
    };

}]);
```

Angular used to unwrap promises, but that was deprecated because it proved to be troublesome and very "magical" (leading to misunderstandings). See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5153

Comment: `getArticle()` must use `getArticles()` because I need to make a loop in articles an extract the right index. How to achieve this without doing another HTTP request? DRY...

Comment: @sylouuu, ok, I understand what you want, but that's not how Angular services and promises work. It's not a matter of DRY either. If you make the $http service call to load the JSON when the service factory function runs, then you're risking to call `getArticle()` or `getArticles()` before the $http call is finished. The only way to really be sure that the ajax call was done is by using promises. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use `$http`'s cache property:

```
Blog.service('ArticleService', ['$http', function ($http) { 

  this.getArticles = function() {
    return $http.get('data/articles.json', {cache: 'myCache'});
  };

  this.getArticle = function (id) {
    return $http.get('data/articles.json', {cache: 'myCache'}).then(function(response) {
       // Parse the response, return the article in question.
    });
  };

}]);
```

Comment: Depends how persistent the OP wants the cache to be. Caching in javascript will endure for the life of the page; the browser cache will span sessions. I'm guessing that `getArticle()` should be in browser cache and `getArticles` should be in js, but only the OP knows.

Comment: I really don't understand why you have to make 2 HTTP requests, because this is a async? My service methods must be available only when the JSON is ready. So what about making a sync request? It seems boring to make `$http.get()` for each method.

Comment: @sylouuu, if you use the `cache` config property as shown above, there won't be two http requests. The method that is called first will trigger a request, and subsequent calls to either method will use the cached response.

Answer (score 0):

```
Blog.service('ArticleService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q)
{
    var self = this;

    this.loadArticles = function ()
    {   

        var deffered = $q.defer();

        $http.get("data/articles.json").then(
                  function (result)
                  {
                      deffered.resolve(result);

                  },
                  function ()
                  {

                      deffered.reject()
                  }

                  );
        return deffered.promise;


    };

    this.getArticles = function ()
    {
        return self.loadArticles;
    };

    this.getArticle = function (id)
    {
        // some stuff to retrieve the object
    };
}]);
```

then in your controller

```
Blog.controller('BlogController', function ($scope, ArticleService)
{
    ArticleService.getArticles().then(function (data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    }, then(function ()
    {
        alert("error")
    })
    );
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

If you want your cache to persist from session to session, then see user3904's answer.

If it is acceptable for the cache to die with the page, then you might consider the following approach :

```
Blog.service('ArticleService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
    var articles = {};
    var loadArticles = function () {
        articles.multi = $http.get("data/articles.json").done(function(a) {
            articles.multi = a;
        });
        return articles.multi;
    };
    var loadArticle = function (id) {
        articles[id] = $http.get("data/articles.json/" + id).done(function(a) {
            articles[id] = a;
        });
        return articles[id];
    };

    this.getArticles = function () {
        return articles.multi ? $q.when(articles.multi) : loadArticles();
    };
    this.getArticle = function(id) {
        id = '' + id;
        return articles[id] ? $q.when(articles[id]) : loadArticle(id);
    };
}]);
```

### Explanation

The cache is the js plain object `articles`.

The two `load...()` functions are private - assuming, as seems reasonable, that they are to be called only by their corresponding `get...()` functions. (This is not particularly significant to the overall solution).

On first call, the two `loadArticles()` caches a promise, which is overwritten with the data delivered by the promise, when that data arrives. The promise is temporarily cached for one reason - in case a second request is made before the data is returned from the server. The `$q.when(...)` in `this.getArticles()` ensures that `loadArticles()` returns promise-wrapped data, regardless of what is currently cached - promise or data.

`this.getArticle()` works similarly to `this.getArticles()`, but accepts (and passes) an id.

This strategy is designed to be storage efficient. By caching only the data long term, the (small) overhead of promise wrappers is avoided. This might be an issue if users are likely to request many individual articles per session.

Storage efficiency is bought at the cost of slightly less efficient delivery of cached articles. `$q.when(...)` will take some extra clock cycles to complete.

It should be quite simple to adapt the code to work the other way round - ie to optimise for delivery at the cost of storage efficiency - ie to store promises long term and avoid the need for `$q.when(...)`.

Both approaches will work and for most applications it's pretty academic which one is adopted.

Comment: My service works with only one JSON file, `articles.json`. I want to get the JSON in an `articles` variable and the use this variable in `getArticles()` and `getArticle(id)`.

Comment: Yes, I know that's what you *want*. What I offer above is something that will actually work!